# Is it possible to backup chatroom messages and export them?

Tags: support, chat

Is it possible to backup chatroom messages and export them?
Actually it is not my question but something that Hindukid had asked me [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57792081#57792081) whether it's possible or not?

> also, asked, if there is any way.. to backup, the conversations we had
> in this Room..
>
> is there any way to backup them?

Comment: Ah there you go: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279311/206319